# Strange ajax submission issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using AJAX to submit my forms. Button with id #submit_btn and checkbox with id #autosave are doing the same things. Button works properly but autosave doesn't. What's wrong with the code?

I noticed that, when i click the submit button the log shows me 2 post's and succesfully adds into db

[image]

But when i check #autosave checkbox, log shows only 1 post in every 5 seconds and doesn't update db table (BUT shows success message, and no error in log)
[image]

**Js side**

```
var int = null;
var counter = 0;
function call() {
    postViaAjax(true)
}


function postViaAjax(autosaveMode) {
dataString = $("#add_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processor/dbadd.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result, status, xResponse) {
                var message = result.msg;
                var err = result.err;
                var now = new Date();
                if (message != null) {
                    if(autosaveMode){
                    $('#submit_btn').attr({
                    'value': 'Yadda saxlanıldı '+ now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds()
                    });
                    }
                    else{
                    $.notifyBar({
                        cls: "success",
                        html: message+' '+ now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds()
                    });
                    }
                }
                if (err != null) {
                    $.notifyBar({
                        cls: "error",
                        html: err
                    });
                }
            }
        });
};




$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.autosave').hide();
    $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
        postViaAjax(false)
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
        if (counter === 0) {
            if (validate()) {
                $('.autosave').show();
                counter++;
            }
        }
        $('#add_form').submit();
    });

    $('#autosave').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            clearInterval(int);
            int = window.setInterval(call, 5000);

        } else {
            $('#submit_btn').attr({
                'value': 'Yadda saxla'
            });
           clearInterval(int);
        }
    });

});
```

PHP side

```
<?php
require '../../core/includes/common.php';

$name=filter($_POST['name'], $db);
$id=filter($_POST['id'], $db);
$title=filter($_POST['title'], $db);
$parentcheck=filter($_POST['parentcheck'],$db);
if(isset ($_POST['parent'])) $parent=filter($_POST['parent'],$db);
else $parent=$parentcheck;  
$menu=filter($_POST['menu'], $db);
$content = $db->escape_string($_POST['content']);


$result=$db->query("UPDATE pages AS p, menu AS m SET m.parent='$parent', m.name='$name', m.showinmenu='$menu', p.id='$id', p.title='$title', p.content='$content' WHERE m.id='$id' AND p.id=m.id") or die($db->error);


if ($result){  
echo "{";  
echo '"msg": "Qeydə alındı" ';
echo "}";  
}else{ 
echo "{"; 
echo
'"err": "error"';  
echo "}";  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure that this is the only issue, but `int` is a [reserved word in older specifications of javascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf).  Pick a real variable name instead of that.  It's also safer to protect against calling `clearInterval()` with junk for a parameter.

```
var autoSaveInterval = null;

$('#autosave').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if (autoSaveInterval) {
            clearInterval(autoSaveInterval);
        }
        autoSaveInterval = window.setInterval(call, 5000);

    } else {
        $('#submit_btn').attr({
            'value': 'Yadda saxla'
        });
        if (autoSaveInterval) {
            clearInterval(autoSaveInterval);
            autoSaveInterval = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for fast answer and trying to help. changed. no success. Also i noticed that when i click button it submits 2 times. But updates db

Comment: You'd have to show your HTML to help further.  If you have a submit button, then you may have to prevent the default behavior.  Can't tell without seeing HTML.  Also, I'm now confused on what your problem really is?

Comment: @jfriend: I cannot find `int` to be listed as a keyword anywhere other than where you have listed and this here (http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/KGsGz/) works well... Is it really a keyword in JavaScript?

Comment: @jfriend i found why log shows post 2 times when i click the button. because i'm using   `$("#submit_btn").click(function () {` and `$("#add_form").submit(function (e) {` together. The problem is, when i click `#submit_btn` it posts via ajax data from form. And php side updates. But when i'm checking #autosave checbox, it posts data and returns success message but doesn't update the db table

Comment: I do not see `int` listed as a reserved word in the ECMAScript specification 5.1 (June 2011) http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf. It was listed as a future reserved word in the v3 specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf.  In any case, there's just no reason to use it.  Might or might not cause problems in some browser, but why take that risk.

Comment: @jfriend can we continue discussion in chat?